# feature extraction of bert and use output as embedding layer for cnn or lstm

Tags: python, keras, feature-extraction, bert-language-model, fusion

I am new to bert models . I want to make fusion between bert and cnn or lstm models for text analysis from searching I found use feature extraction of last layer from bert before classifier step but I donn't understand how to do that using python especially keras library so i need any suggestion  with illustration

I found  this got  but got errors so i need help to understand this code

```
input_ids=[]
attention_masks=[]

for row in df['posts'].tolist():
    bert_inp=tokenizer.encode_plus(str(row),add_special_tokens = True,max_length =64,pad_to_max_length = True,return_attention_mask = True)
    input_ids.append(bert_inp['input_ids'])
    attention_masks.append(bert_inp['attention_mask'])

input_ids = torch.cat(input_ids, dim=0)
attention_masks = torch.cat(attention_masks, dim=0)

config = BertConfig.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased", output_hidden_states=True)
model = BertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased", config=config)

#with torch.no_grad():
outputs = model(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_masks)

embeddings = outputs[2][1:]

def get_CLS_embedding(layer):
    return layer[:, 0, :].numpy()
    
cls_embeddings = []
for i in range(12):
    cls_embeddings.append(get_CLS_embedding(embeddings[i]))
```

> edit : I fixed previous error by using tensor.concat instead of torch.cat
> but I found another error in this part

```
 from tensorflow.python.ops.numpy_ops import np_config
 np_config.enable_numpy_behavior()
config = BertConfig.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased", output_hidden_states=True)
model = BertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased", config=config)

outputs = model(input_ids2, attention_mask=attention_masks2)
```

I got this error

> > > 5 outputs = model(input_ids2, attention_mask=attention_masks2)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py in forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, token_type_ids, position_ids, head_mask, inputs_embeds, encoder_hidden_states, encoder_attention_mask, past_key_values, use_cache, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
936             raise ValueError("You cannot specify both input_ids and inputs_embeds at the same time")
937         elif input_ids is not None:
--> 938             input_shape = input_ids.size()
939         elif inputs_embeds is not None:
940             input_shape = inputs_embeds.size()[:-1]

TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not callable

Comment: You seem to be using a mix of pytorch and tensorflow tensors

Comment: what is the solution for that ?

Comment: Pick a framework and stick to it. Typically, don't use `torch.cat` operations on tensorflow objects - you'll want to use `tensorflow.concat` instead.

Comment: thank you it worked